# How to target only landscape mobile devices without affecting desktop via CSS?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, landscape, portrait

Is there a simple way to target landscape **mobile** devices without affecting desktop ones, without entering the screen size for every device?
If not, is there a single best resolution to target most of the users?
Nowadays mobile screens can have a resolution equal or grater than most desktop screens, I can't see why many use rules for resolutions below 640x480.

For example, to target *portrait* devices (99% are mobile), one could write his rules in

```css
/*Global and desktop rules*/

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
/*Mobile overwrites*/
}
```

However, the same query for `orientation: landscape` would affect desktop users as well.
My temporary workaround is to use `vw`, `vh` and `vmin`, but I would like to know if there's a better way.

Would a `mobile` CSS media simplify web developers' job?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can mix CSS Media Queries for **orientation** to detect landscape mode and **hover** + **pointer** to detect a touch device.

```css
@media (orientation: landscape) and (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) {
/* your CSS to target only landscape mobile users */
}
```

For a reference to detect a touch device with only CSS here's a good article on [medium](https://medium.com/@ferie/detect-a-touch-device-with-only-css-9f8e30fa1134).

The best solution is to use JavaScript to detect the device and add a class to the `<body>` or the `<html>` in order to add your CSS.
You can have a look at [**current-device**](https://github.com/matthewhudson/current-device), you just include the script, that then updates the `<html>` section with the appropriate classes based on the device's characteristics.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a query `@media pointer`, which determines whether the the user has a pointing device (like a mouse). Since mobile devices don't have a pointer, you could combine `not: pointer` and `orientation: landscape`, like this

```
 @media (not: pointer) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the min-resolution media feature to target devices with a high pixel density screens (i.e. most modern mobile devices) and the orientation media feature to target those devices in landscape mode.

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {
   /* CSS rules for mobile devices in landscape orientation go here */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
    @media (orientation: landscape) {    

}
```

Comment: This affects desktop devices as well